# VMWare: copy and paste only for some desktop environments

Tags: linux, vmware-player

I have a problem with a Linux guest (Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit) on a Windows 10 host: copy and paste from/to host works when using a desktop environment like LXDE, but fails when using a plain startx session (`dwm` only). Is there some D-Bus service or the like required for copy and paste to work?

Comment: Make sure VMware Tools have been installed and are up to date in each guest machine.  When you copy (say Control C) and then try to paste with Control V, it may not work (depends on machine and circumstances). Right click and Paste Selection. This always works for me. Windows 10 Host, Kali Guest, Ubuntu Guest, Windows 7 Guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, cross-system copy/paste always needs some sort of service running as part of your X11 session (i.e. not a system-wide service) and communicating clipboard changes to the host, e.g. via VMBus or VirtIO or XenBus or some other dedicated host-guest IPC system.

Desktop environments have a standard place to auto-start things from – the ["XDG Autostart"](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/0.5/ar01s02.html) directories at `/etc/xdg/autostart/` and the per-user version `~/.config/autostart/`. That's where you'll find a .desktop file that launches the appropriate VMware helpers for clipboard etc.

If you don't have a session manager to handle XDG autostart, then you can either copy the `Exec=` value into your own startup script (~/.xinitrc), or you can use tools such as `dex` to "launch" a .desktop file as-is.

(D-Bus is not involved here, as the only IPC that's internal to the guest is between the app you're copying from and the VMware clipboard helper daemon – which is handled by the X11 protocol, like any other clipboard usage. These helper daemons *may* use D-Bus for other purposes though.)